# Increment counter multiple times

Tags: java

Suppose I only want to print out 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50 on the console using Java.

I am currently doing so with the following piece of code:

```
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter <= 50){
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter++; 
        counter++; 
        counter++; 
        counter++; 
        counter++; 
    }
```

I would like to know if this is the most efficient way to do it. Is there a way to do it without having to write the counter increment 5 separate times?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to add 5 every iteration?

Comment: You would have serious problems if you wanted to increment 1000 each iteration, eh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write:

```
counter += 5;
```

Comment: This would be the most efficient :) way to increment counter by X value.

Answer (score 5):

you would use a for loop like this:

```
    for (int n = 0; n <= 50; n += 5) {
        // do something
    }
```

`+=` is called a compound assignment operator and evaluates to 
`n = n + 5`.

Comment: You probably want to include 50.

Answer (score 3):

no,  its not efficient

use

```
counter = counter + 5;
```

or

```
counter += 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int counter = 0;

    while(counter <= 50){
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter += 5;
    }
```

or below if you want even less lines :)

```
int counter = -5;

    while(counter <= 50){
        System.out.println( counter += 5);
    }
```